# Проход по массивам разного размера одновременно

Tags: python

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно выводить в цикле элементы всех массивов по одному с каждого, но у каждого массива свой размер. И, массив с меньшим количеством элементов подходит к концу, нужно начать выводить его элементы сначала, но продолжать выводить элементы других массивов.
Пример:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3]
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array3 = [1]
```

Нужен вывод 10 элементов таким образом:

```
1 1 1
2 2 1
3 3 1
1 4 1
2 5 1
3 1 1
1 2 1
2 3 1
3 4 1
1 5 1
```

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с помощью базового Python без привлечения дополнительных библиотек:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3]
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array3 = [1]

ls1 = len(array1)
ls2 = len(array2)
ls3 = len(array3)

for i in range(10):
    print (array1[i % ls1],array2[i % ls2],array3[i % ls3])
```

Результат:

```
1 1 1
2 2 1
3 3 1
1 4 1
2 5 1
3 1 1
1 2 1
2 3 1
3 4 1
1 5 1
```

Comment: Спасибо, а если массивов у меня к пример, 100? То мне нужно создать массив из их размеров и сопоставлять также, правильно?

Comment: Разумеется. Вам надо сначала создать массив массивов (список списков), потом  - список их длин, а потом в теле главного цикла  сделать дополнительный (внутренний) цикл, выполняющий проход по вашим массивам. Тогда у вас может быть хоть 10, хоть 100 хоть миллион массивов - скрипт останется работоспособным. Кстати, нечто подобное вам придется сделать и во всех приведенных ниже вариантах решения задачи.

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз. Использую Ваш вариант, всем устраивает.

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import cycle, takewhile

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [1]

max_len = max(map(len, [a, b, c]))
it = enumerate(zip(*map(cycle, [a, b, c])))

for n, v in takewhile(lambda i: i[0] < max_len, it):
    print(*v)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот вам для примера:

```
import itertools

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [1]

rep = 10

ca = itertools.cycle(a)
cb = itertools.cycle(b)
cc = itertools.cycle(c)


while rep:
    print(f"{next(ca)} {next(cb)} {next(cc)}")
    rep-=1
```

На выходе:

```
1 1 1
2 2 1
3 3 1
1 4 1
2 5 1
3 1 1
1 2 1
2 3 1
3 4 1
1 5 1
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import cycle

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [1]

max_len = max(map(len, [a, b, c]))
it = list(map(cycle, [a, b, c]))
while max_len:
    max_len -= 1
    print(*map(next, it))
```